# How can i Change tab background color on selection using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Although the question is really common I really couldn't quite find a definite answer. I have two tabs 'Tab1' and 'Tab2' I want the color of the active tab to change when the user clicks on it. Is there any way I can do it by pure js?

CSS

```
#tab1:hover, #tab2:hover, #tab3:hover {
  background: teal;
}

#tab1Content, #tab2Content, #tab3Content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #B00098;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tab button{
      color:#1e84d8;
    /*margin-bottom: 0 px;*/
    background-color: #e7f6ff;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.1s;
    width:50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #20a3eb;
}
      #tab1btn{
                border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
                padding: 20px;
                overflow: hidden;
                color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
                font-size: 25px;
                font-style: initial;
                font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
            }

      #tab2btn{
                border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
                padding: 20px;
                overflow: hidden;
                color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
                font-size: 25px;
                font-style: initial;
                font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
            }
```

HTML

```
<div class="tab" >
  <button  id= "tab1btn"  value="Chasis_1">Chasis 1</button>
  <button  id= "tab2btn" value="Chasis_2" >Chasis 2</button>  
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723528/how-to-create-tabs-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

With the code you have given, I have added only one `css` property to have class `active` and a `background-color` to the active as `green` ..,

```
.active {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

The `JS` part inclusion,

```
const tab1btn = document.getElementById('tab1btn');
const tab2btn = document.getElementById('tab2btn');

function changeBackground(event){
  const active = document.querySelector('.active');
  if(active){
    active.classList.remove('active')
  }
  event.target.className = "active";
}


tab1btn.addEventListener('click', changeBackground.bind(this));
tab2btn.addEventListener('click', changeBackground.bind(this));
```

I believe you have only these two button and need to change the background color based on the selection,

Get those buttons using, `getElementById()` and make `addEventListener()` to each button separately and have a common function `changeBackground()` which has the code that changes the active class between switching of tabs..

```js
const tab1btn = document.getElementById('tab1btn');
const tab2btn = document.getElementById('tab2btn');

function changeBackground(event){
  const active = document.querySelector('.active');
  if(active){
    active.classList.remove('active')
  }
  event.target.className = "active";
}


tab1btn.addEventListener('click', changeBackground.bind(this));
tab2btn.addEventListener('click', changeBackground.bind(this));
```

```css
#tab1:hover, #tab2:hover, #tab3:hover {
  background: teal;
}

#tab1Content, #tab2Content, #tab3Content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #B00098;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tab button{
      color:#1e84d8;
    /*margin-bottom: 0 px;*/
    background-color: #e7f6ff;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.1s;
    width:50%;
    border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #20a3eb;
}
      #tab1btn{
                border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
                padding: 20px;
                overflow: hidden;
                color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
                font-size: 25px;
                font-style: initial;
                font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
            }

      #tab2btn{
                border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
                padding: 20px;
                overflow: hidden;
                color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
                font-size: 25px;
                font-style: initial;
                font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; 
            }

.active {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab" >
  <button  id= "tab1btn"  value="Chasis_1">Chasis 1</button>
  <button  id= "tab2btn" value="Chasis_2" >Chasis 2</button>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this not necessarily you need to use js from what I understood from your question this might be solution you are looking for

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp

It is basically the Css selector focus

So you do element:focus then you can change the color

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very tricky  to do. You can do it in very simple steps:

1. Create an active class style for tabs
2. Then add onClick events on your button (you can also do it using `addEventListener`
3. When tab is clicked, remove active class from active tab, and add it to the clicked tab

Example -

JS:

```
function selectTab (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // select current active tab and remove active class (if-any)
  let activeTab = document.querySelector('.tab > .active');
  if (activeTab) activeTab.classList.remove('active');

  e.target.element.classList.add('active');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tab">
  <button id="tab1btn" value="Chasis_1" onClick(e => selectTab(e))>
    Chasis 1
  </button>
  <button id="tab2btn" value="Chasis_2" onClick(e => selectTab(e))>
    Chasis 2
  </button>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tab > button.active {
  background-color: #cecece;
}
```