# Make the tab content clickable and setActive based on radio

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i am trying to make the each tabcontent div clickable and when click it will proceed based on radio Active. Can i ask for help how to do that? i only make the radio clickable but not the content. i want the content to be clickable also, same like radio behavior. but im not sure how will i gonna do that. still learning. Thank you really appreciate it.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background: #f69ec4;
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
      }
      .tabs {
        /* width: 100%; */
        flex-direction: row;
        /* background: #fff; */
        box-shadow: 0 2rem 2rem #00000080;
        /* min-height: 100px; */
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 3px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 20px;
        flex-grow: 4;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 2px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      label#one-tab {
        margin-left: 1rem;
      }

      h2 {
        color: #000;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2em;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }

      .warpper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .tab {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin: 0px 2px;
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
        width: 18% !important;
        margin-right: 1.4rem;
      }

      .panels {
        flex-direction: row;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 2rem 2rem #00000080;
        min-height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 3px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 20px;
        flex-grow: 4;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 2px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      .panel {
        animation: fadein 0.8s;
        width: 20%;
        margin: 0rem 1rem;

        height: 194.98px;

        background: linear-gradient(180deg, #424856 0%, #282934 100%);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border-radius: 8px;
      }

      @keyframes fadein {
        from {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        to {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }

      .panel-title {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .radio {
        display: none;
      }

      #one:checked ~ .panels #one-panel,
      #two:checked ~ .panels #two-panel,
      #three:checked ~ .panels #three-panel,
      #four:checked ~ .panels #four-panel {
        display: block;
        border: 4px solid #c8d1f5;
      }

      #one:checked ~ .tabs #one-tab,
      #two:checked ~ .tabs #two-tab,
      #three:checked ~ .tabs #three-tab,
      #four:checked ~ .tabs #four-tab {
        background: red;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        height: 10rem;
        object-fit: cover;
        color: #000;
      }
      .coin {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 10rem;
        position: relative;
      }
      hr {
        margin: 1.875em 0;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: solid 10px #000000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Pure CSS Tabs</h2>
    <hr class="dashed-2" />
    <div class="warpper">
      <input class="radio" id="one" name="group" type="radio" checked />
      <input class="radio" id="two" name="group" type="radio" />
      <input class="radio" id="three" name="group" type="radio" />
      <input class="radio" id="four" name="group" type="radio" />

      <div class="tabs">
        <label class="tab" id="one-tab" for="one">
          <div class="coin">
            <img src="one.png" />
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="tab" id="two-tab" for="two">
          <div class="coin">
            <img src="one.png" />
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="tab" id="three-tab" for="three">
          <div class="coin">
            <img src="one.png" />
          </div>
        </label>
        <label class="tab" id="four-tab" for="four">
          <div class="coin">
            <img src="one.png" />
          </div>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="panels">
        <div class="panel" id="one-panel">
          <div class="panel-title">Title1</div>
          <p>Content1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" id="two-panel">
          <div class="panel-title">Title2</div>
          <p>Content2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" id="three-panel">
          <div class="panel-title">Title3</div>
          <p>Content3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" id="four-panel">
          <div class="panel-title">Title4</div>
          <p>Content4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JS instead of use `input`, when click add class `active`

Solution here: [how-to-create-tabs-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723528/how-to-create-tabs-in-javascript)